# How to use mongodbadapteroptions in nextauth

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

I have found that mongodbadapter in nextauth takes another argument as options like below

```
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(connectDB,{
    collections:{
      Users:""
    }
  })
```

as you can see first one is database connection function and second is options inside it it has collections and inside that it has users and other tables created by nextauth I wanted to know how to use this this is not specified in the nextauth docs. I wanted to know if it can used to define mongodb user schema or model.

and if anyone know how to add custom schema for the user in mongodb please provide the solution i want to add more custom fields in user model thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeGNp.png)I got to know about this mongodbadapter options from vs code i hovered over the mongodb adapter